# iOS App crashing on Region Format change

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mkmapview

My iOS App(based on Maps) is working fine, but when I change Region Format to Malay(in iOS 6), app is crashing. It works fine in previous versions of iOS.

Comment: What is the crash error? Where in your code does it crash?

Comment: It is really hard for someone else to help you with only this much info.  You should look at the crash log on the device and see if it can help you find the class where the crash is occurring, and maybe give you an idea of where in the class to look for the problem.  Region Format affects many things.

Answer (score 0):

Region format errors often come when dealing with string to number conversion. In the UK, US and many more places one thousand and a half is written "1,000.5" (although comma is optional). In France they'd write that as "1.000,5". If your code is doing string to number conversions then look at that bit and if you can't see the issue come back here with more information, you haven't given us much to go on.